# react native how to iterate over json data and render in component

Tags: json, react-native

im new to react native and i have been able to fetch json data from server successfully. how do i pass the object into an array and render in my component. Here is my code

i've tried iterating over the object using .map() and i get "undefined is not a function". Ive also tried to convert the object into an array using Object.values and i get error "value for message cannot be cast from readablenativearray to string"

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    //useraccountdetails will contain the object from the server
        this.state = {
            useraccountdetails: [],
        }

        this.loaduser_account_details= this.loaduser_account_details.bind(this)

    }

    componentWillMount() {
      //this function will fetch the data from the server
        this.loaduser_account_details()
    }


    loaduser_account_details() {

        fetch('http://10.162.101.247/camfilaapiv2/commands/loggedin_user_account_details.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'text/plain',
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                globaluseridDB: modulevariables.globaluserid,
            })
        }).then((response) => response.text())
            .then((responseJson) => {


                var jsonconvertedrows = JSON.parse(responseJson);
                var finaldata = JSON.stringify(jsonconvertedrows)


                this.setState({ useraccountdetails: finaldata });
                Alert.alert("User details", this.state.useraccountdetails)

            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            })
    }


    //alert(this.state.useraccountdetails) gives me this [{"user_id":"107","username":"sam","year":"6"}]

    render(){
 return (

            /**page setup */
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#203546', flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}>

                {/**body */}
                <Grid>

                     {
                        this.state.useraccountdetails.map((count)=>{
                            <Text>{count.username}</Text>
                        })
                    }



                </Grid>


            </View>
        )
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your JSON data response?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd alert(responseJson) gives `[{"user_id":"107","username":"sam","year":"6"}]`

Comment: okay, then try to assign jsonconvertedrows to usersccountdetails in the state.

Comment: Your API call to the server is a promise, maybe render function works first before the API call is actually done.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd ive assigned jsonconvertedrows to userdetails in the state like u said but its not showing in the render function

Comment: @MohamedSameer any way i could fix that?

Comment: @sam change componentwilllmount to componentdidmount, for async calls 'componentdidmount' is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is because you are iterating over a string in your render. `this.state.useraccountdetails` is a string once your response is successful as you are setting it as the result stringified. To correct this all you will need to do is correct your setState to

```
this.setState({ useraccountdetails: jsonconvertedrows });
```

Comment: Please also note that in your render are only iterating over the result but not actually returning the <Text> list. Correct your map by removing the parentheses `this.state.useraccountdetails.map((count) => <Text>{count.username}</Text>)`

Comment: i set it to like u said but its not showing in the component. Im getting error "cant find variable count"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code?

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    //useraccountdetails will contain the object from the server
        this.state = {
            useraccountdetails: [],
        }

        this.loaduser_account_details= this.loaduser_account_details.bind(this)

    }

    componentWillMount() {
      //this function will fetch the data from the server
        this.loaduser_account_details()
    }


    loaduser_account_details() {

        fetch('http://10.162.101.247/camfilaapiv2/commands/loggedin_user_account_details.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'text/plain',
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                globaluseridDB: modulevariables.globaluserid,
            })
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {


                //var jsonconvertedrows = JSON.parse(responseJson);
                //var finaldata = JSON.stringify(jsonconvertedrows)


                this.setState({ useraccountdetails: responseJson });
                Alert.alert("User details", this.state.useraccountdetails)

            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            })
    }


    //alert(this.state.useraccountdetails) gives me this [{"user_id":"107","username":"sam","year":"6"}]

    render(){
 return (

            /**page setup */
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#203546', flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}>

                {/**body */}
                <Grid>

                     {

                      return this.state.useraccountdetails.map((count)=>{
                          return(
                            <Text>{count.username}</Text>
                           )
                        })
                    }



                </Grid>


            </View>
        )
}
```

You are try to change the response to 'text', please change it from `response.text()` to `response.json()`

Comment: there's an error now which says "value for message cannot be cast from readablenativearray to string"

Comment: please comment the alert code line, or change to  Alert.alert("User details", JSON.stringify(this.state.useraccountdetails)) this.

Comment: im getting this error now please." Json parse error: unexpected identifier "object"

Answer (score 0):

Change  `this.setState({ useraccountdetails: Object.values(jsonconvertedrows) });` as shown in code and try it:

```
loaduser_account_details() {

        fetch('http://10.162.101.247/camfilaapiv2/commands/loggedin_user_account_details.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'text/plain',
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                globaluseridDB: modulevariables.globaluserid,
            })
        }).then((response) => response.text())
            .then((responseJson) => {


                var jsonconvertedrows = JSON.parse(responseJson);
                var finaldata = JSON.stringify(jsonconvertedrows)


                this.setState({ useraccountdetails: Object.values(finaldata) });
                Alert.alert("User details", this.state.useraccountdetails)

            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            })
    }
```

Comment: there's an error now which says "value for message cannot be cast from readablenativearray to string"

Comment: still giving me the same error message unfortunately